# Can Tablets deal with USB Sound Cards? 

Tags: audio, tablet, usb-peripherals, microphone

I've found [this thing on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-2-0-to-Mic-Speaker-Audio-5-1-channel-3D-Sound-Card-Adapter-Virtual-Mini-New-/260921302512?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cc01f1df0). It converts the USB to a microphone input and a jack-speaker output. I'm just curious, if my tablet is compatible with it as the description doesn't explicitly mentions it.

My device is rooted if that makes any difference.

Comment: Please DO NOT use URL shorteners here. Use the full, real, URL.

Comment: As far as I know, the Galaxy SIII is the only android device that currently supports USB Audio.  I heard that Cyanogenmod also enables this though.

Answer (score 2):

Extremely doubtful, to the point where I'm confident saying no, it wouldn't work.  It would require either the OS dev team having included Linux drivers that would work with the USB device, or the USB device manufacturer having released Android-compatible drivers that you could install on your tablet yourself.

Comment: It's not vendor specific - these things use the USB Audio standard, and don't need device specific drivers.  All it would take is google enabling USB Audio in the stock OS.  Really don't understand why they haven't done this.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that product is an DAC. As long as your device has OTG/USB host support, it'll work.

Comment: As far as I know, the Galaxy SIII is the only android device that currently supports USB Audio.  Stock ICS does not.